# How to give file path in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, relative-url

I am starting a project on `Eclipse` and I am facing a problem while I am trying to link external `CSS` files to my `index.html` file. This is my file structure in `Eclipse.`

```
- MyProject
 - WebContent
   - META-INF
   - WEB-INF
     - css
     - js
   - index.html
```

I tried this path in my `index.html` file.

```
<link href="WEB-INF/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but the `css` file was not taken. I tried this in outside environment of `Eclipse.` It works fine.
What is the problem here?

If I can have a simple explanation about how to give the file path / what is scenario I should follow, it will be very helpful for me

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Files inside the `WEB-INF` folder cannot be externally accesed. Move the `css` folder to another directory and it should work as expected.